# How to look at specifc ranges every 131 rows to perform formatting

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range

My Title may have appeared difficult to understand and I apologize if this was the case but essentially for my macro I am trying to set specific formatting every 131 rows for a specific range if these specific ranges meet certain conditions. This may sound strange but basically I am working on an excel file which will constantly get updated yearly. The excel file has tables for each year. There is specific information in each table. Each table is located about 20 rows from each table in this excel file. Some rows in the file are supposed to consist of only formulas and some rows are supposed to consist of only hardcoded numbers/empty cells etc. I'll show the code I have currently available and the project should make more sense once I show the code, at least I hope.

```
Sub HardcodedVSFormulas_Nissan()
Dim cell As Range
Dim Ws As Worksheet


''FY18/19
Dim Range18_1, Range18_2, Range18_3, Range18_4, Range18_5, Range18_6, Range18_7, Range18_8, Range18_9, Range18_10, Range18_11, Range18_12, Range18_13, Range18_14, Range18_15, Range18_16, Range18_17, Range18_18, Range18_19, Range18_20, Range18_21, Range18_22, Range_23, Range_24 As Range
Dim Range18NoF_1, Range18NoF_2, Range18NoF_3, Range18NoF_4, Range18NoF_5, Range18NoF_6, Range18NoF_7, Range18NoF_8, Range18NoF_9, Range18NoF_10, Range18NoF_11, Range18NoF_12, Range18NoF_13, Range18NoF_14, Range18NoF_15, Range18NoF_16, Range18NoF_17, Range18NoF_18, Range18NoF_19, Range18NoF_20, Range18NoF_21, Range18NoF_22, Range18NoF_23, Range18NoF_24 As Range

''FY19/20
Dim Range19_1, Range19_2, Range19_3, Range19_4, Range19_5, Range19_6, Range19_7, Range19_8, Range19_9, Range19_10, Range19_11, Range19_12, Range19_13, Range19_14, Range19_15, Range19_16, Range19_17, Range19_18, Range19_19, Range19_20, Range19_21, Range19_22, Range_23, Range_24 As Range
Dim Range19NoF_1, Range19NoF_2, Range19NoF_3, Range19NoF_4, Range19NoF_5, Range19NoF_6, Range19NoF_7, Range19NoF_8, Range19NoF_9, Range19NoF_10, Range19NoF_11, Range19NoF_12, Range19NoF_13, Range19NoF_14, Range19NoF_15, Range19NoF_16, Range19NoF_17, Range19NoF_18, Range19NoF_19, Range19NoF_20, Range19NoF_21, Range19NoF_22, Range19NoF_23, Range19NoF_24 As Range

''FY18/19 Ranges with formulas
Set Range18_1 = Range("C1285:Q1285") '
Set Range18_2 = Range("C1289:Q1291") '
Set Range18_3 = Range("C1293:Q1300") '
Set Range18_4 = Range("C1305:Q1314") '
Set Range18_5 = Range("C1316:Q1319") '
Set Range18_6 = Range("C1324:Q1332") '
Set Range18_7 = Range("C1334:Q1334") '
Set Range18_8 = Range("C1339:Q1351") '
Set Range18_9 = Range("C1353:Q1353") '
Set Range18_10 = Range("C1358:Q1359") '
Set Range18_11 = Range("C1364:Q1364") '
Set Range18_12 = Range("C1368:Q1371") '
Set Range18_13 = Range("C1373:Q1376") '
Set Range18_14 = Range("C1381:Q1388") '
Set Range18_15 = Range("C1393:Q1393") '
Set Range18_16 = Range("C1395:Q1395") '
Set Range18_17 = Range("C1397:Q1397") '

Set Range18_18 = Range("O1293:Q1314") '
Set Range18_19 = Range("O1334:Q1351") '
Set Range18_20 = Range("O1353:Q1370") '
Set Range18_21 = Range("B1284:B1370") '
Set Range18_22 = Range("S1284:S1370") '

Set Range18_23 = Range("C1360:Q1363") '
Set Range18_24 = Range("C1365:Q1367") '


Set Range18NoF_1 = Range18_1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range18NoF_2 = Range18_2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range18NoF_3 = Range18_3.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range18NoF_4 = Range18_4.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range18NoF_5 = Range18_5.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range18NoF_6 = Range18_6.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range18NoF_7 = Range18_7.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range18NoF_8 = Range18_8.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range18NoF_9 = Range18_9.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range18NoF_10 = Range18_10.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range18NoF_11 = Range18_11.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range18NoF_12 = Range18_12.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range18NoF_13 = Range18_13.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range18NoF_14 = Range18_14.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range18NoF_15 = Range18_15.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)


Set Range18NoF_16 = Range18_16.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range18NoF_17 = Range18_17.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range18NoF_18 = Range18_18.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range18NoF_19 = Range18_19.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range18NoF_20 = Range18_20.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range18NoF_21 = Range18_21.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range18NoF_22 = Range18_22.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range18NoF_23 = Range18_23.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range18NoF_24 = Range18_24.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)


''FY19/20 Ranges with Formulas
Set Range19_1 = Range("C1416:Q1416")
Set Range19_2 = Range("C1420:Q1422")
Set Range19_3 = Range("C1424:Q1431")
Set Range19_4 = Range("C1436:Q1445")
Set Range19_5 = Range("C1447:Q1450")
Set Range19_6 = Range("C1455:Q1463")
Set Range19_7 = Range("C1465:Q1465")
Set Range19_8 = Range("C1470:Q1482")
Set Range19_9 = Range("C1484:Q1484")
Set Range19_10 = Range("C1489:Q1490")
Set Range19_11 = Range("C1495:Q1495")
Set Range19_12 = Range("C1499:Q1502")
Set Range19_13 = Range("C1504:Q1507")
Set Range19_14 = Range("C1512:Q1519")
Set Range19_15 = Range("C1524:Q1524")
Set Range19_16 = Range("C1526:Q1526")
Set Range19_17 = Range("C1528:Q1528")

Set Range19_18 = Range("O1424:Q1445")
Set Range19_19 = Range("O1465:Q1482")
Set Range19_20 = Range("O1484:Q1501")
Set Range19_21 = Range("B1415:B1501")

Set Range19_23 = Range("C1491:Q1494")
Set Range19_24 = Range("C1496:Q1498")


Set Range19NoF_1 = Range19_1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range19NoF_2 = Range19_2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range19NoF_3 = Range19_3.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range19NoF_4 = Range19_4.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range19NoF_5 = Range19_5.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range19NoF_6 = Range19_6.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range19NoF_7 = Range19_7.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range19NoF_8 = Range19_8.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range19NoF_9 = Range19_9.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range19NoF_10 = Range19_10.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range19NoF_11 = Range19_11.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range19NoF_12 = Range19_12.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range19NoF_13 = Range19_13.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range19NoF_14 = Range19_14.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range19NoF_15 = Range19_15.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)


Set Range19NoF_16 = Range19_16.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range19NoF_17 = Range19_17.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range19NoF_18 = Range19_18.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range19NoF_19 = Range19_19.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range19NoF_20 = Range19_20.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range19NoF_21 = Range19_21.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range19NoF_22 = Range19_22.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)

Set Range19NoF_23 = Range19_23.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
Set Range19NoF_24 = Range19_24.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)

For Each cell In Range18_1
        If Intersect(cell, Range18NoF_1) Is Nothing And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 50000
        End If
    Next cell

    For Each cell In Range18_2
        If Intersect(cell, Range18NoF_2) Is Nothing And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 50000
        End If
    Next cell

    For Each cell In Range18_3
        If Intersect(cell, Range18NoF_3) Is Nothing And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 50000
        End If
    Next cell


    For Each cell In Range18_4
        If Intersect(cell, Range18NoF_4) Is Nothing And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 50000
        End If
    Next cell


    For Each cell In Range18_5
        If Intersect(cell, Range18NoF_5) Is Nothing And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 50000
        End If
    Next cell


    For Each cell In Range18_6
        If Intersect(cell, Range18NoF_6) Is Nothing And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 50000
        End If
    Next cell

    For Each cell In Range18_7
        If Intersect(cell, Range18NoF_7) Is Nothing And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 50000
        End If
    Next cell


    For Each cell In Range18_8
        If Intersect(cell, Range18NoF_8) Is Nothing And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 50000
        End If
    Next cell


    For Each cell In Range18_9
        If Intersect(cell, Range18NoF_9) Is Nothing And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 50000
        End If
    Next cell


    For Each cell In Range18_10
        If Intersect(cell, Range18NoF_10) Is Nothing And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 50000
        End If
    Next cell


    For Each cell In Range18_11
        If Intersect(cell, Range18NoF_11) Is Nothing And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 50000
        End If
    Next cell


    For Each cell In Range18_12
        If Intersect(cell, Range18NoF_12) Is Nothing And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 50000
        End If
    Next cell


    For Each cell In Range18_13
        If Intersect(cell, Range18NoF_13) Is Nothing And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 50000
        End If
    Next cell


    For Each cell In Range18_14
        If Intersect(cell, Range18NoF_14) Is Nothing And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 50000
        End If
    Next cell


    For Each cell In Range18_15
        If Intersect(cell, Range18NoF_15) Is Nothing And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 50000
        End If
    Next cell


    For Each cell In Range18_16
        If Intersect(cell, Range18NoF_16) Is Nothing And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 50000
        End If
    Next cell


    For Each cell In Range18_17
        If Intersect(cell, Range18NoF_17) Is Nothing And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 50000
        End If
    Next cell


    For Each cell In Range18_18
        If Intersect(cell, Range18NoF_18) Is Nothing And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 50000
        End If
    Next cell


    For Each cell In Range18_19
        If Intersect(cell, Range18NoF_19) Is Nothing And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 50000
        End If
    Next cell


    For Each cell In Range18_20
        If Intersect(cell, Range18NoF_20) Is Nothing And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 50000
        End If
    Next cell


    For Each cell In Range18_21
        If Intersect(cell, Range18NoF_21) Is Nothing And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 50000
        End If
    Next cell


    For Each cell In Range18_22
        If Intersect(cell, Range18NoF_22) Is Nothing And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 50000
        End If
    Next cell
```

With this code it can be seen that Range18_1 and Range19_1 are 131 rows apart from each other and with Range 19_2 and Range19_2 this is the same case. All these 24 ranges for each table should be separated 131 rows apart. This section of code only looks at rows which should consist of only formulas(unless cells are empty and contain nothing) so if there are cells which aren't formulas or empty cells then these cells within these specified ranges will turn green. This indicates to the user to fix these green cells to make them formulas instead of hard coded numbers. Obviously what I have now is inefficient because new tables are always being created in this excel file so I'm curious if there is a way to essentially automatically look every 131 rows at these specific ranges and perform this conditioning I have coded.

Maybe it wasn't clear, an example of what I'm trying to accomplice is to look at C1285:Q1285 and then look at C1416:1416 and then look at C1547:Q1547 and so on. Looking every 131 rows. Is this even possible in VBA because I have no clue but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Something like `for i = `1 to lastRow step 131` using `Range("A" & i)`?

Comment: I don't understand how that will work. The table has rows with hardcoded numbers between rows with formulas and vice versa. I want the macro to look for instance at the range C1234 to Q1239 and then look at C1365 to Q1270 and then look at C1496 to Q1501. The macro I'm trying to make should keep looking every 131 rows forever. Actually I may be able to use what you write and change it to maybe work something out.

Comment: the loop jump 131 rows. at every iteration you can look at a given cell, then the four cells below it (using another smaller loop from 0 to 4 and offset, for example) For more details, please edit your question to add sample data and expected outcome